# c# program like HangMan

Tags: c#

so i need to make code that is similar to game HangMan, where you need to guess the word by entering letters. Everything works kinda fine, but i need, when i enter wrong letter, it to say, that the letter is not in that word. Help Please!

```
 string secretword = "m a n a m e j e f f";
        string[] secretarray = secretword.Split(' ');
        string letter = "";
        string[] guessarray = new string[secretarray.Length];
        int counter = 0;
        int guess = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < guessarray.Length; i++)
        {
            guessarray[i] = "_";
        }
        foreach (string s in guessarray)
        {
            Console.Write(s + " ");
        }
        while (guess != secretarray.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Enter a letter: ");
            letter = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < secretarray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (secretarray[i] == letter)
                {
                    guessarray[i] = letter;
                    guess++;
                }

            }
            if (guess != 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in guessarray)
                {
                    Console.Write(s + " ");
                }

            }
            else if (guess == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is no letter like that!");
            }

            counter++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You guessd the word with tries: " + counter);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do the job.

```
        string secretword = "m a n a m e j e f f";
        string[] secretarray = secretword.Split(' ');
        string letter = "";
        string[] guessarray = new string[secretarray.Length];
        int counter = 0;
        int guess = 0;
        bool goodguess = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < guessarray.Length; i++)
        {
            guessarray[i] = "_";
        }
        foreach (string s in guessarray)
        {
            Console.Write(s + " ");
        }
        while (guess != secretarray.Length)
        {
            goodguess = false;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Enter a letter: ");
            letter = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < secretarray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (secretarray[i] == letter)
                {
                    guessarray[i] = letter;
                    guess++;
                    goodguess = true;
                }

            }
            if (goodguess == true) 
            {
                foreach (string s in guessarray)
                {
                    Console.Write(s + " ");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is no letter like that!");                   
            }

            counter++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You guessd the word with tries: " + counter);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean to track if the guess matched any letters.

```
while (guess != secretarray.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Enter a letter: ");
    letter = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    bool correct = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < secretarray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (secretarray[i] == letter)
        {
            guessarray[i] = letter;
            guess++;
            correct = true;
        }
     }

     if (guess != 0)
     {
         foreach (string s in guessarray)
         {
            Console.Write(s + " ");
         }
      }
      else if (!correct)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("There is no letter like that!");
      }

      counter++;
}
```